# SQL Find Replacement Character as a part of a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need help with writing a query which will find [Replacement Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) in SQL table.

I have multiple cells which contain that character and I want to find all those cells. This is how the value of cell looks like this:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You may have a collation problem. That question mark "character" is rather a symbol representing a character that cannot be properly displayed the way it's currently encoded. Is your goal to permanently strip these characters out or would you use them if you could?

Comment: First I want to find all the cells where those special characters exist and then I want to replace them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (ID INT, WORDS VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES (1, 'A�AA')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES (2, 'BBB')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES (3, 'CC�C')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES (4, 'DDD')

SELECT * FROM @TEST WHERE WORDS LIKE '%' + NCHAR(UNICODE('�')) + '%'

UPDATE @TEST
SET WORDS = REPLACE(WORDS, NCHAR(UNICODE('�')), 'X')

SELECT * FROM @TEST WHERE WORDS LIKE '%' + NCHAR(UNICODE('�')) + '%'
SELECT * FROM @TEST
```

Comment: Can you explain it more as I see no difference in result of your query and this one : `UPDATE @TEST SET WORDS = REPLACE(WORDS,'�', 'X')`.

Comment: FriendlyManCub thank you very much, Unicode function is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

The UNICODE suggestion didn't work for me - the � character was being treated as a question mark, so the query was finding all strings with question marks, but not those with �.

The fix posted by Tom Cooper at this link worked for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/2754165e-7ab7-44b0-abb4-3be487710f31/black-diamond-with-question-mark

```
-- Find rows with the character
Select * From [MyTable]
Where CharIndex(nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, MyColumn) > 0

-- Update rows replacing character with a !
Update [MyTable]
set MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, '!')
```

Comment: That did the trick for me. Since there are thousands of unicode values that map to �, I think it's also helpful to repeat how Tom Cooper got to the number 65533. It looks like unicode numbers 55296 to 57343 and 65533 are currently �. If you know what record has the character, you can do something like SELECT Unicode(Substring(column_name, 3, 1)) FROM table_name WHERE id = 2

Answer (score 0):

In Sql you can able to replace the black diamond symbol.

Input :  You�ll be coached through alternating
Output : You will be coached through alternating
select  replace(description, nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2,' wi')  from [Fitnesstable]
where description  LIKE '%' + '. You'+NCHAR(55296) +'ll'+ '%'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32026102)

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE - character to ,

```
UPDATE TblName
SET fildname= REPLACE(fildname, NCHAR(UNICODE('-')), N'،')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code to search the query for the character you wish to find.

```
select field_name from tbl_name where instr(field_name, 'charToBeSearched') > 0;
```

This query will find and selects the records which has replacement character.

Comment: There is no `instr` function in T-SQL.

Comment: In T-SQL you can use charindex instead: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/216e25e3-43ec-4f25-9040-0279d5494704/tsql-question-instr-equivalent?forum=transactsql